# How to JUnit test ParseException

Tags: java, testing, junit, parseexception

So, I am working on a project, and I have to test if my method catches a `ParseException` when it occures. Here is how the method that I need to test looks like:

```
public void convertToModel(final BuildStone bs, final TextBuildStone model) {
    try {
        model.setBeginDateRange(ProjectDateConverter.projectDateToCalendarDefaultMin(bs.getFromDate(), true));
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        SystemContext.getLogger().warning(
                this,
                "treatGeneralData",
                "Date not converted: {0}, BeginDate set at MinDate",
                bs.getFromDate());
        model.setBeginDateRange(CalendarConstants.getMinDate());
    }
```

So I have to test when this method catches a `ParseException`.

The method that throws a ParseException is `projectDateToCalendarDefaultMin` , here is the code of that method:

```
public static Calendar projectDateToCalendarDefaultMin(final BigDecimal dateValue, final boolean useMinDate) throws ParseException {
    return dateValue == null ? ProjectDateConverter.projectDateStringToCalendar(null, useMinDate, false) : ProjectDateConverter
            .projectDateStringToCalendar(dateValue.toString(), useMinDate, false);
```

The method that throws ParseException is called `projectDateStringToCalendar`. Here is how that one looks like:

```
private static Calendar projectDateStringToCalendar(final String dateValue, final boolean useMinDate, final boolean useMaxDate)
        throws ParseException {
    if (useMinDate && useMaxDate) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("useMinDate and useMaxDate may not be set as true ");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(dateValue)) {
        if (useMinDate) {
            return CalendarConstants.getMinDate();
        } else if (useMaxDate) {
            return CalendarConstants.getMaxDate();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
...
final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(dateValue));

    return gc;
}
```

So this is where the `ParseException` is finally thrown, at the `parse()` method. `ParseException` is from `text.parse` package and the method parse looks like this:

```
 public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
{
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    Date result = parse(source, pos);
    if (pos.index == 0)
        throw new ParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + source + "\"" ,
            pos.errorIndex);
    return result;
}
```

What I have already tried to do is to set `bs.getFromDate` to null but the test would always be red. I used `@Test(expected: ParseException.class)` annotation in my test, but I just can't make it go green. Perhaps `bs.getFromDate` is not the right value that is being parsed?

Does anyone have any other idea how to make this test work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you paste the JUnit Test method? Maybe some other Expcetion occurs before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so the simplest way is to:

- Call you method with arguments that will throw the **ParseException**
- If no exception is thrown to the test it means it was caught in the
  method

Looking into your code there is another way you can do:
I see you set begin date range on the model if the exception has been caught:
**model.setBeginDateRange(CalendarConstants.getMinDate());**

So in your test you can check if:
 **model.getBeginDateRange()** equals **CalendarConstants.getMinDate()**

 (You may need to get the actual version of the model before that check depending on how your code works)

Hope that helps.

Comment: The another way was actually the only way to test this method. Thank you!

Comment: For a pure unit test, you shouldn't be inducing an exception in another method. You should be mocking the call to it.

Answer (score 1):

The JUnit `@Test(expected)` annotation requires that you be precise about which exception will be thrown.

If you assume `ParseException`, but `NullPointerException` is thrown, the test will show as failed.

Try `@Test(expected = Exception.class)` and see if that handles all of them.

Comment: It takes a class literal, not a String, so use `@Test(expected=ParseException.class)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a mock framework (e.g Mockito, EasyMock) to mock the call to the projectDateToCalendarDefaultMin method and throw a ParseException.

Your post condition assertion would be that the beginDateRange property of model has been set to CalendarConstants.getMinDate().

Answer (score 0):

I think that another exception is thrown and you are not catching it. Namely, when you call this method:

```
projectDateToCalendarDefaultMin(final BigDecimal dateValue, final boolean useMinDate) throws ParseException {
```

with a `null` value for `dateValue` you get `NullPointerExcpetion` and that's why your test is red.

Comment: So what do you suggest to set at the dateValue in order to get ParseException? The dateValue is type "BigDecimal".